# IntelliJ - What is the keyboard shortcut to toggle the project file tree?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am on windows.

In intelliJ Ultimate, there is at the top right corner of the window a horizontal tab labeled "1.Project". Pressing `shift` + `esc` will hide the file tree. However, pressing the same key combination does not unhide it.

How can I unhide this? Or create a custom binding that will toggle hide to unhide if it is already hidden?

Comment: Have you tried `alt` + `1` ? Underlined characters are `alt` shortcuts

Comment: Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clément Baconnier was correct. `alt + 1` was the key binding. `cmd + 1` on osx.

Alternatively, I learned how to fish using the Action pane `ctrl + shift + a` that let me search for "Project" which exposed the keyboard shortcut.